# PYTHON/DJANGO: "SUser.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I have a problem with adding new custom user to the database. I know thare's some threads about it on the internet but I couldn't find solution for my problem. After hitting "Submit" button in registration page which template is here:

```
{% extends 'strona/Main.html' %}
{% block body %}
< form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        < /br >
        {{ field }}
        < /br >
        < /br >
    {% endfor %}
    < button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button >
< /form >
{% endblock %}
```

it keeps saying that: **"Cannot assign "< SimpleLazyObject: < django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x038B5A70 >>": "SUser.user" must be a "User" instance."**

***Source Codes:***

**VIEWS.PY**

```
class RegPanelView(View):
panel = RegPanel
template_name = 'strona/RegistrationTemp.html'
registration = None

def get(self, request):
    form = self.panel(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    # form = self.panel(data=request.POST)
    form = self.panel(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        # user = form.save(commit=False)

        # username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password1 = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = form.cleaned_data['password2']

        if password1 == password2:

            newuser = form.save(commit=False)
            newuser.user = request.user
            newuser.save()

            return redirect('strona:index')
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class SUser(models.Model):
# User = user_model()
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
# last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
# is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
relations = models.ManyToManyField('self')
# is_anonymous = False
# is_authenticated = True

USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('', )
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class RegPanel(UserCreationForm):

# password = forms.CharField(max_length=16, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
# first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
# last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
# is_staff = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

# birthday = forms.DateField(required=False)

class Meta:
    model = SUser
    fields = ['username', 'is_staff', 'first_name', 'last_name']





def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    # user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["passwosrd1"])
    if commit:



        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.save()
        # if commit:
        # user.save()

    return user
```

**SETTINGS.PY:**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
```

**EDIT**

FULL ERROR TRACEBACK:

> File
>   "C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.3-py3.5.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.3-py3.5.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.3-py3.5.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.3-py3.5.egg\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.3-py3.5.egg\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Dawid\PycharmProjects\Zadanie\strona\views.py" in post
>     97.                 newuser.user = request.user
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.3-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py"
>   in **set**
>     211.                     self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /index/register/ Exception Value: Cannot
>   assign "< SimpleLazyObject:  >": "SUser.user" must be a "User" instance.

Please could someone help me out? 
Kind regards.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is a registration form, so the user can't possibly be logged in yet. So why are you trying to save the current user to the new user object?

Comment: So how could I save new user after " if password1 == password2:" ?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your post.

Comment: @KlausD.Done, added

Answer (score 1):

Django lazy loads `request.user` so that it can be either `User` or `AnonymousUser` depending on the authentication state.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated(): #then request.user will be `User` instance
    newuser = form.save(commit=False)
    newuser.user = request.user
    newuser.save()
```

Comment: It returns False so my user cannot be saved

Comment: That means you have to `login` first. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/

Comment: Thanks, really helped me get rid of the errors.